# Как хранятся структуры в памяти?

Tags: c++, память, структуры

Прочитал, что поля структуры хранятся в памяти последовательно(в порядке объявления) (+- платформ.зависимое выравнивание). Вопрос такой: как влияют методы в структурах на их расположение в памяти?
Предположим, есть структура вида:

```
struct my_Struct{
double n;
void meth();
char ch;
    }
```

Как экземпляр этой структуры (а именно его поля) будут расположены в памяти? 
И ещё, применимы ли все знания по структурам(и их расположению в памяти) к классам?
И есть ли какая-то разница (с точки зрения памяти) между обычными методами и перегрузками / конструкторами / деструкторами?

Comment: с точки зрения C++ структура - это класс, только в нём по дефолту все члены публичные, а в классе - приватные

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во-первых, как правильно заметили в комментариях, **в С++ [структур нет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/2752075). Ключевое слово `struct` создает классы**, в которых поля и родители по умолчанию публичные.
Какой-то другой разницы между `struct` и `class`, с точки зрения стандарта, насколько я знаю, нет.

---

**[Начиная с C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), поля действительно хранятся в порядке объявления.**

---

**До C++23 они хранятся в порядке объявления только если спецификатор доступа** (`public/private/protected`) **у них одинаковый**.

Если спецификатор доступа одинаковый, то из двух полей в памяти идет раньше то, которое в определении класса написано выше. Если спецификатор доступа у двух полей разный, то компилятор вправе расположить их относительно друг друга как угодно.

В частности, соответствующий стандарту компилятор может располагать все поля в памяти по порядку, игнорируя спецификаторы доступа. А может сложить в кучку отдельно `private`, `protected` и `public`. Могут быть какие-то другие варианты.

Пруф: [**[class.mem]/19**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-19)

> Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified. Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions and virtual base classes.

---

У каждого экземпляра одного класса, очевидно, свой набор из всех нужных полей.

Но вот **методы** у всех экземпляров одного класса общие - они **не занимают место в экземплярах класса и не влияют на его размер в байтах**.*
(Не считая указателя на vtable для виртуальных функций.)

Обычно методы реализуются так же, как и обычные функции, но с добавленным невидимым параметром `this`. Так что нет смысла в каждом экземпляре хранить какую-то информацию о методах, не считая vtable pointer.

---

*<sub>Хотя разницы между `class` и `struct` быть не должно, и хотя не виртуальные методы на размер класса влиять не должны, мне у нас на SO недавно попался пример, в котором GCC с определенными настройками убирал выравнивание из `struct` как только к нему добавляли один любой метод, либо когда `struct` меняли на `class`. Видимо для совместимости с каким-то С-шным компилятором. Если кто-то найдет больше информации по этой теме, буду благодарен.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

1. Методы никак не влияют на расположение в памяти ([посмотреть](https://godbolt.org/z/i9MEK7)). Методы априори не могут занимать память объектов (методы ведь не создаются для каждого объекта отдельно). Метод - (на низком уровне) это функция для которой просто передается указатель `this` с помощью регистра процессора. Из ранее приведенной ссылки:

`lea rax, [rbp-12]` - взятие адреса объекта (начала последовательности байт принадлежащих объекту) и помещение его в регистр. Далее метод будет работать как обычная функция, зная, что в нужном регистре хранится указатель на текущий объект.

2. Различие между структурой и классом только в доступности по умолчанию: структуры - public, классы - private (все члены по умолчанию имеют указанный спецификатор доступа) ([class](http://eel.is/c++draft/class)).
3. Перегруженные функции - это разные функции (каждая из них имеет собственный адрес). Какая именно функция будет вызвана компилятор решит во время компиляции (в отличии от виртуальных методов). [Посмотреть](https://godbolt.org/z/nS7yZl).